# How to set variable from imported .csb file in iMacros?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-scraping, imacros

Please help me setting variable as imported file's column data.

Just for an example:
Manually I can search by name or type this link (https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=Wilhelem%20Gabriella) and click on the name or profile picture and I go the that person's profile page and I simply copy the URL (https://www.facebook.com/gabriella.wilhelem).

I see that I can not set variable as an element from imported csv file column.

My question is can iMacros actually do something like this? if yes, how can it be done? Since I am not programmer, actual codes are appreciated.

Address.csv file contains 2 columns(FBfirstName, FBlastName)

```
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !VAR1 {COL1}
SET !VAR2 {COL2}

URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q={{!VAR1}}20%{{!VAR2}}
'TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR1}}<SP>{{!VAR2}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q={{!COL1}}%20{{!COL2}}
'TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR1}}<SP>{{!VAR2}}
SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*
```